# Chart Building Issue With SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pie-chart

I am in the process of trying to build a pie chart based on data from a table in SQL Server, Here is my code, both ASP.NET and c#:

**ASP.NET**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            title: 'My Bills'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert("Failure");
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

**C#**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<object> GetChartData()
    {
        string Chartquery = "SELECT a.[amount] AS 'Amount', DATENAME(Month,a.[myDate]) +' '+ convert(varchar(4),Year(a.[myDate])) As 'Month Year' "
            + "FROM [myTable] a "
            + "left join [mySecondTable] b on a.[ID] = b.[ID] "
            + "left join [myThirdTable] c on c.[code] = b.[code] "

            + "WHERE c.[myName] = John Doe";

        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ToString();
        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();

        chartData.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Amount", "Month Year"
        });

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Chartquery))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                            sdr["Amount"].ToString(), sdr["Month Year"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return chartData;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `C#` code returns exactly what it should, I have debugged it and it works great. My program compiles, builds and runs, but when it loads the page I get the error on the page that says `Pie chart should have a first column of type string`. So my guess is it has something to do with the ASP code.

I know I posted a lot of code, but wanted to provide everything I had to give a better idea at what I was doing and for you all to point out any mistakes.

Any advice on how to fix the above error of `Pie chart should have a first column of type string`?

**EDIT:**

I added `.ToString()` in the while loop and it fixed the issue with the string. Now the page is loading with no errors, but it is like the chart isn't filling with data, even though my `return chartData` is returning data.... The only thing showing up on my page is the chart title

Any sugggestions?

Comment: Is the error a Javascript error when you're attempting to draw the chart in your page (in the success function)?

Comment: I just found that when I change the 2 objects to "ToString()" in my while loop that it gets rid of the error. It loads the page, but doesn't show my pie chart. It only shows my My title "My Monthly Bills", even though I know I am getting the data from my select statement, it is stored in "chartData"

Comment: What is the value of "r" in your success function?

Comment: Can you add console.log(r) to the beginning of your "success" function and check the results in the console? It sounds like the data is not being serialized properly.

Comment: To be honest I am not entirely sure, I was following a tutorial online. My assumption was it was the data being added to the pie chart?

Comment: Yes, I will do that now

Comment: It returns "[Object object]"

Comment: Can you expand that :) For example in Chrome, typically you can examine the contents of the object you log to the console.

Comment: I actually had to do it in an alert, it was giving  me "console undefined" when I tried to do the console.log :(

Comment: Can you join this? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71368/charthelp

Comment: It says I have to have 20 reputation, let me logon to my other accound and try to join it there. Stand by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you write

```
chartData.Add(new object[]
{
    sdr["Amount"].ToString(), sdr["Month Year"].ToString()
});
```

change it to

```
chartData.Add(new object[]
{
    sdr["Month Year"].ToString(), sdr["Amount"]
});
```

And that should fix it. Also, change the header row!